# How to reference a model that is nested inside a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that is inside a folder in my models folder:

/app/models/api/new_user_request.rb

```
class Api::NewUserRequest
  attr_accessor :user_id, :location_id
end
```

How do I write the allowed params method now?

I tried:

```
    def new_card_request_params
      params.require(:new_user_request).permit(:user_id, :location_id)
    end
```

But I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: new_card_request)
```

I need to reference it like Api::NewCardRequest but how do I do that with the params require?

Answer (score 0):

If in the form you work with an object of the class `Api::NewUserRequest`, then when submitting the form the params are passed in `api_new_user_request` hash (unless it is overwritten by `as` option of [form_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) helper). So validating code in the controller should be:

```
def new_card_request_params
  params.require(:api_new_user_request).permit(:user_id, :location_id)
end
```